# What is the size of an LTL formula?

Tags: model-checking

What is generally meant by the size of an LTL formula, |p|, in terms of complexity? Number of atomic propositions, depth or something else?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: .. may be the length of the string that describes LTL formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of complexity it makes sense to count the number of **X** and **U** operators used in the formula. Please note that you can regard operators like **F**, **G**, **R** and **W** as syntactic sugar that uses **U** (see [Syntax of LTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic#Syntax)).

**Justification**:
When model checking the system you have to consider each possible future for each state of the system. So you have to consider that a sub-formula of the form **X**... or ...**U**... might be true or false. Thus, you have 2^n possibilities for each state, where n is the number of **X** and **U** operators.

More precisely, when you use e.g. Lichtenstein and Pnueli's algorithm to verify the formula, you search for strongly connected components (SCC) in a graph of a size <= s*2^n with s being the number of states.

If your LTL syntax allows past operators, too, then you can add the operators **Y** and **S** analogously.